# Capping gas price with geth

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions

Is there anyway to set a maximum gas price for sending any transaction with any account? I know I could hard code this in, but wondering if this is fortunately built in?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current gas price for a connected node, using web3.js.

```
web3.eth.gasPrice
 ( Or )
web3.eth.getGasPrice(callback(error, result){ ... })
```

If you want to set gas price for a transaction save gas price in to variable and if you want your transactions should takes place add extra value.

Eg:

```
var gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice;
console.log(gasPrice.toString(10)); // "18000000000"
```

For more details:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgasprice

Comment: @ user32096 I hope your issue is solved, can you mark ans as solved. It could helpful for community to find ans very easily.